# Matlab table output displaying twice

Tags: matlab, text-files, tabular

In my Matlab file, I have an array of data for which I am going to display in a table and also write to a txt file.

My code looks like this:

```
Cat = {'Weight of Bridge(lbs)';'Maximum Load (lbs)';'Toughness by cat.     
failure (in lbs)';'Strength to Weight Ratio'; 'Toughness to Weight Ratio'};
Bridge_1 = [weight1;max1;tough1;swr1;twr1];
Bridge_2 = [weight2;max2;tough2;swr2;twr2];

T = table(Bridge_1,Bridge_2, 'RowNames',Cat)
writetable(T,'Samantha_Hochstat_ML_4_results.txt','WriteRowNames',true);
type 'Samantha_Hochstat_ML_4_results.txt';
```

The output has a very nice table that is correctly formatted and also prints the data the same way it would print to the txt file (so displaying twice, one correctly and once without formatting).

I would appreciate any help on removing the second unformatted text, or suppressing it.

Comment: Why are you displaying it if you don't want to display it? Remove the last line

Answer (score 0):

change

```
T = table(Bridge_1,Bridge_2, 'RowNames',Cat)
```

to

```
T = table(Bridge_1,Bridge_2, 'RowNames',Cat);
```

this will suppress the formatted output.